# How to call WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message for LTEXT control in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I created the dialog form for MFC class by editing .rc file with form designer as follows, 
[image]

It is taken as **LTEXT**. I want to change the color of that text using **WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message**.
I used the subclass as follows,

```
HWND name_message = ::GetDlgItem(hwnd_, IDC_EDIT_OUTPUT_STRING);
g_EditTxtViewWndProc = (WNDPROC)(LONG_PTR)GetWindowLongPtr(name_message, GWLP_WNDPROC);
SetWindowLongPtr(name_message, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)(EditTxtViewProc));

LRESULT CALLBACK
EditTxtViewProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {

  static HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));

  switch( msg )
  {
      case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
      {
        HDC hdC = (HDC)wp;
        SetTextColor(hdC, RGB(255, 0, 0));
        SetBkColor(hdC, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        return (INT_PTR)hBrush;
      }
   }
}
```

In above case it does not call to the *WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message*. I am beginner to the Window Programming.

Can anyone help me that how to subclass as above?

Comment: `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` is sent to the control's **parent**, not to the control itself. So the **parent's** wndproc needs to handle it, not the control's wndproc. This is clearly stated in the [`WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-ctlcolorstatic) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[Remy Lebeau's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53124475/how-to-call-wm-ctlcolorstatic-message-for-ltext-control-in-c#comment93151313_53124475) is correct. You need to handle this message from within the *parent*'s window procedure.

In MFC, you could also directly use CWnd::OnCtlColor. Most controls send this message to their parent (usually a dialog box) to prepare the pDC for drawing the control using the correct colors.

For more information, refer to MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#onctlcolor