# How can I manually trigger WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC call

Tags: c++, window, controls, sendmessage

I have an array of static windows which I want to change the text color to on hover.

How can I trigger the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message to be called?

**Fig 1.1**
`Button` declaration

```
std::map<int, Button *> buttons;
```

**Fig 1.2**
`Button` definition

```
for(int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++)
{
    buttons[i] = new Button(i, 0, 32 + (i * 20), w, h, segoe16, hwnd);
}
```

**Fig 1.3**
`Button` constructor:

```
Button(LPCWSTR text, int x, int y, int width, int height, HFONT font, HWND parent)
{
    hwnd = CreateWindow
    (
        L"BUTTON",
        text,
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_FLAT,
        x,
        y,
        100,
        30,
        parent,
        (HMENU)RES_ID,
        NULL
        NULL
    );
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETFONT, (LPARAM)font, TRUE);
}
```

**Fig 1.4**
`ColorStatic` function:

```
INT_PTR ColorStatic(LPARAM lParam, WPARAM wParam, bool print = false)
{
    DWORD CtrlID = GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam);
    if ((int)CtrlID == this->resourceID)
    {
        HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) wParam;
        if(!hovered)
        {
            SetTextColor(hdcStatic, this->FG);
        }
        else
        {
            SetTextColor(hdcStatic, this->FGH);
        }
        SetBkColor(hdcStatic, this->BG);
        return (INT_PTR)CreateSolidBrush(this->BG);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Fig 1.5**
`HoverCheck` function:

```
/// This check is performed in the general window loop.
void HoverCheck()
{
    
    inside = bounds.Within(MousePos(), GetScreenPos());
    if(inside && !hovered)
    {
        hovered = true;
        if(buttonType == TEXT_STATIC)
        {
            // WHAT I HAVE TRIED
            SendMessage(hwnd_parent, WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, 0,(LPARAM)hwnd_button); 
        }
        else
        {
            SendMessage(hwnd_button,STM_SETIMAGE,IMAGE_ICON,(LPARAM)hover_icon);
        }
    }
    else if(!inside && hovered)
    {
        SendMessage(hwnd_button,STM_SETIMAGE,IMAGE_ICON,(LPARAM)normal_icon);
        hovered = false;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or overlooking something in the `SendMessage` call?
Extensive debugging has shown me that neither passing parent nor child as the hwnd will trigger a message call.

I have tried triggering the WM_`CTRCOLORSTATIC` message call by using
`SendMessage(hwnd_button, WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, 0,(LPARAM)hwnd_button)` but this has no effect.

**My code works fine when the windows have images on them** as I make a call to `STM_SETIMAGE` on hover (See Fig 1.5).
However, when there is no image the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message is not sent by the system.
I have tried triggering the `WM_CTRCOLORSTATIC` message call by using:

`SendMessage(hwnd_button, WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, 0,(LPARAM)hwnd_button)` but this has no effect

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53124475/how-to-call-wm-ctlcolorstatic-message-for-ltext-control-in-c) and could not find any other questions came even close to explaining how to send the message. Only how to handle it.

Comment: I am experimenting right now with Invalidate Rect. I think it might be the solution.

Comment: Invalidate rect causes the message to be sent. Solved!

Comment: Even though your code now works as expected, it contains a common memory leak bug. Within `ColorStatic()` you constantly create new solid brushes without removing them after use.

From the `CreateSolidBrush()` API doc:
"When you no longer need the HBRUSH object, call the `DeleteObject()` function to delete it".

Comment: Why can't you just redraw the control? That will send a `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` during the redraw process, I guess.

Comment: Thank you halifix, I appreciate this feedback.